# load aspx page containing ReportView into div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to load an aspx page into a div using jquery using the below code:

```
$("#divInsideParentPage").load("http://localhost/WebForm.aspx");
```

My WebForm.aspx contains ReportViewer control and contains rdlc reports.

The issue is that the actual report is not getting rendered.

The reports gets loaded correctly when I use iFrame. I think jQuery .load is just loading the static html content inside the aspx page and not executing the whole code to load the rdlc report.

Comment: Is that happening in all browsers?

Comment: Check the error console : F12